# Permission Error with homebrew

Tags: macos, permissions, homebrew

Whenever I try to install something with homebrew, I get this error:

```
Error: Permission denied - /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/tmux.brewing
```

and I am just using the normal command

```
brew install tmux
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo chown -R your_username /Library/Caches/Homebrew` should do it. Possible but unlikely you'll also need to `chmod -R o+w /Library/Caches/Homebrew`.

If you have a multi-user Homebrew setup, consider using [brewdo](https://github.com/zigg/brewdo).

Answer (score 0):

The solution [posted here to a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/450207/38941) worked.

Namely:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```